# Прокрутки блоков в блоке (HTML + CSS)

Tags: html, css

Есть задача: надо сделать div (блок), в который вложены другие блоки (div). Контейнер имеет фиксированную высоту и ширину, заданную в пикселях; вложенные блоки также имеют фиксированную высоту и ширину. Если блоки не помещаются в контейнер по горизонтали, то должна появится горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Проблема в том, что если блоки не помещаются, они переносятся на новую строку, а скролл не появляется.

Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/sj296/27/

```
<div id = "ct">
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
    <div class = "gt">
    </div>
</div>​
```

-

```
ct {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100px;
}
.gt {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так - http://jsfiddle.net/sj296/28/

Comment: Это, как я понял, немного не то, что хотелось вопрошающему.
Если сделать
<pre><code>
.gt{
    width:20px;
</code></pre>
то видно, что блоки все же переносятся на след. строку

Answer (score 1):

нужно поместить все внутренние блоки в один общий и обязательно указать ему ширину